# How to print by press of a button a simple quote in swift at random from an array?

Tags: ios, swift

I am completely new to coding.

I started using this app called MIMO and learned a few bits and pieces. In one chapter they let us code a simple "dice app" where by pressing a button a number from 1 - 6 appears. Now I wanted to rewrite that so that at the button press the app displays a quote from a predetermined array.

I am completely stuck, however.

Here's what I got:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quotesLabel: UILabel!

    let quotes = ["Quote1!", "Quote2!"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count)))
    let randomQuote = quotes[randomIndex]
    print(array[randomIndex])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically any arbitrary code must be run in a method, in this case in an `IBAction` which is triggered when the button is pressed. The method `viewDidLoad` is not needed.

- Change the code to

  ```
  import UIKit
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var quotesLabel: UILabel!

      let quotes = ["Quote1!", "Quote2!", "Quote3!", "Quote4!"]

      @IBAction func showRandomQuote(_ sender : UIButton) {
          let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count)))
          let randomQuote = quotes[randomIndex]
          quotesLabel.text = randomQuote
      }
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder drag a button into the canvas of the view controller
- Connect (<kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>drag</kbd>) the button to the `IBAction` and the label to the `IBOutlet`
- Run the app and press the button

Comment: thank you for the quick help!! now it seems I can't connect the button somehow... it says: "Could not insert new action connection: Could not find any information for the class named quotes" the dragging ^ didn't work for me either. is that control + drag? /// it seems that if i change the sender to any it works. would still like to know what made the difference.

Comment: Yes ⌃-drag means Control-drag. The action connection with specific sender `UIButton` works only if the affected UI element is an `UIButton`.

Comment: thanks! :) it worked! that was what I wanted to achieve. Only one thing left maybe you could help with that too: the quotes are sometimes quite long and some get cut of on both sides. I changed the label lines to 0 and put it into word wrapping but it won't change. looking at the main.storyboard everything looks fine but once i run the simulator it cuts it of again

Comment: You might have to add AutoLayout constraints (without a fixed height).